# Centering figures in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, floats

I am using tikz and the environment {figure} to have 4 graphs on the same page, but the result is not convincing, i want to center more (the figures must be more to the left and the vertical space between then must be smaller, see the screen). Is there a command to do it?

```
  \begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.46\linewidth}
 \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   ....
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}[c]{.46\linewidth}  
 \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
      ...
   \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
 \begin{minipage}[c]{.46\linewidth}
 \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   ...
   \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.46\linewidth}
 \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: `TiKZ` pictures are like a char, if all of them have similar sizes you can even use a simple `tabular` to align them. Another problem would be to add a particular caption for each one. But looking around you'll find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried putting them in a `tabular` environment? You can easily center it with `\centering`.

Comment: The vertical separation is due to the fact that you have two figures on a page with no text.  If you combined them into one figure (with a blank line or \par between them) you would have no space at all.  The off-center is probably due to the tikzpictures being wider than the minipages (which are redundant anyway).

Comment: If you need more detailed help than the suggestions above, please provide a proper Minimal Working Example (MWE) which we can compile i.e. code for a complete document.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add `\subcaption`s then you will need the minipages.  Otherwise, why bother?

The `\hfil`s provide equal spacing to the left, right and between.
There is an automatic `\hfil` (actually `\parfillskip`) at the end of a paragraph.

The tikzpictures default to bottom alignment.  Using the `baseline` option will change that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}% generic text
\usepackage{showframe}% outline text area

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \hfil
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (4,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \hfil
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (4,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \hfil
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (4,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \hfil
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (4,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As separate images:

[image]

with use of `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% option 'showframe' is only for show page layout ...

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,legend entries={$x$,$x^2$}]
    \addplot {x};
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
    &   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,legend entries={$x$,$x^2$}]
            \addplot {x};
            \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}                                           \\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,legend entries={$x$,$x^2$}]
    \addplot {x};
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
    &   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,legend entries={$x$,$x^2$}]
            \addplot {x};
            \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your anwsers! I don't know why but it's not working. When i try to do the code for 2 figures, they are not centered such as the figures of x and x², maybe too large? When i try the code for 4 images, i have this Tex error : TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
\pgfsyssoftpath@thepath ...totoken {102.43904pt}{8
5.001pt}\pgfsyssoftpath@li...
l.570 \end{tabularx}

Comment: MWE in my answer doesn't work?  It had to works! If this is a case, than try to upgrade your LaTeX distribution. If this doesn't help, than you have something broken in your LaTeX installation. In use of your images, you need to take a care, that they are not to wide. In my MWE this is assured with `width=\linewidth` in option for `axis`.

Comment: I forgot the `linewidth`, that's good for the two figures. But, when i try for the four figures, it's still the same problem... The exact is error : " ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
<template> \pgf@matrix@padding \endtemplate
l.568 \end{tabularx}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me. ".  I will try to upgrade my LaTex distribution.