# Incorrect graphing using pgf plot, graph appears to be inverted with random noise

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

*Shorter version of the problem below (scroll down a bit)*

I am trying to make this figure here (hand drawn part at the bottom is supposed to be the graph that comes up incorrectly)
[image]

The equation for the curve takes the form of this (equation in top left):
[image]

So I wrote my code as follows:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
\begin{scope}[scale=1]
\clip  (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
\draw [domain=-10:-170,samples=200] plot ({3+1*cos(\x)}, {6+1*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-220,samples=200] plot ({3+2*cos(\x)}, {6+2*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-250,samples=200] plot ({3+3*cos(\x)}, {6+3*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-360,samples=200] plot ({3+4*cos(\x)}, {6+4*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-360,samples=200] plot ({3+5*cos(\x)}, {6+5*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-360,samples=200] plot ({3+6*cos(\x)}, {6+6*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-360,samples=200] plot ({3+7*cos(\x)}, {6+7*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=-10:-170,samples=200] plot ({5+1*cos(\x)}, {6+1*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=40:-180,samples=200] plot ({5+2*cos(\x)}, {6+2*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:360,samples=200] plot ({5+3*cos(\x)}, {6+3*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-360,samples=200] plot ({5+4*cos(\x)}, {6+4*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-360,samples=200] plot ({5+5*cos(\x)}, {6+5*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-360,samples=200] plot ({5+6*cos(\x)}, {6+6*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [domain=0:-360,samples=200] plot ({5+7*cos(\x)}, {6+7*sin(\x)}); 
\draw [densely dashed,thick] (4,6.4) +(-61.7:0.65) -- +(-61.7:8);
\draw [densely dashed,thick] (4,6.4) +(-118.3:0.65) -- +(-118.3:8);
\draw [densely dashed,thick] (4,5.8) -- (4,0);
\end{scope}
\fill[white] (2,6) rectangle (6,8);
\draw (2,6) rectangle (6,8);
\draw (3,6.2) circle (0.1);
\draw (5,6.2) circle (0.1);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm]
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
trig format=rad,
,
]
\addplot [
    black,
domain={-0.73}:{0.73},
    samples=201,
]
    {2*(3*pi*sin(sin(\x))^(2)*(3*pi*sin(\x))^(-2)};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However it produces this image here:
[image]

I currently have no idea why it does not look like the graph in the second image.

**IF THAT WAS TOO LONG TO READ HERE IS THE PROBLEM**, The following code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
trig format=rad,
,
]
\addplot [
    black,
domain={-0.73}:{0.73},
    samples=500,
]
    {2*(3*pi*sin(sin(\x))^(2)*(3*pi*sin(\x))^(-2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Renders this function:
[image]
Not this function
[image]

Comment: The function you plot with pgfplots is not the same as the function you plot in your example picture. Try `\addplot[domain=-0.73:0.73,samples=50,smooth]{2*(sin(3*pi*sin(x))^(2)*(3*pi*sin(x))^(-2))};`.

Comment: oh whoops, also is there a way to center the pgf plots and tikz image with each other and set them so that they have the same width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a problem with how you applied the `BODMAS` :)

I hope the below correct script helps.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
trig format=rad,
,
]
\addplot [
    black,
domain={-0.73}:{0.73},
    samples=500,
]
    {2*(sin(3*pi*sin(\x))^(2)*(3*pi*sin(\x))^(-2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: whoops my bad... :)

Comment: is there a way to center the pgf plots and tikz image with each other and set them so that they have the same width?

Comment: @sabhoque may be this could help https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321520/centering-figures-in-tikz

Comment: @sabhoque You can set the width of the plots and also use `groupplots`.